# Is it possible to bundle / install gems from a local cache?

Tags: ruby, caching, rubygems, bundle

I have  bunch of gems on my computer that I want to use in a chef recipe.

I know it is possible to put them in a directory like /tmp/gems and just:

```
cd /tmp/gems
gem install *.gem
```

Is it possible to put all gems in one directory where I can install them with bundler without downloading them again?

```
cd /somedir/my_rails_project
bundle
```

I want to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add local directories to your [Gemfile](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html) (example from the docs):

```
gem "nokogiri", :path => "~/sw/gems/nokogiri"
```

Alternatively, you can set up a local Git repository with the gems in it and write a Gemfile like this:

```
gem "gem1", :git    => "file:///tmp/gems",
            :branch => "gem1"
```

Comment: That is a solution, but it would be better if it is transparent (No changes in my Gemfile).

Comment: You can write script for install gems (with gem install) from your cache.

Answer (score 33):

`bundle install --local` should be what you want.  From the [bundle-install](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html) manpage:

```
--local
    Do not attempt to connect to rubygems.org, instead using just the 
    gems located in vendor/cache. Note that if a more appropriate 
    platform-specific gem exists on rubygems.org, this will bypass 
    the normal lookup.
```

Comment: And if deploying (with capistrano or similar) use --deployment and make sure to symlink vendor/bundle to shared/vendor_bundle or similar (as mentioned in http://bundler.io/v1.5/deploying.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
bundle package
```

> Locks and then caches the gems into ./vendor/cache.
>
> The package command will copy the .gem files for your gems in the
>   bundle into ./vendor/cache. Afterward, when you run bundle install,
>   Bundler will use the gems in the cache in preference to the ones on
>   rubygems.org.

http://bundler.io/v1.6/bundle_package.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH` configuration key:

> `cache_path` (`BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH`): The directory that bundler will place cached gems in when running `bundle package`, and that bundler will look in when installing gems. Defaults to `vendor/bundle`.

Source: https://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_config.html#LIST-OF-AVAILABLE-KEYS

In GitLab CI, I defined this value in the environment of runners: `"BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH=/cache-ci/bundle"`, this directory is mounted automatically in CI runners.

Then `bundle install` will install gems from the cache directory (once cache will be populated).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a local cache for the purpose of speeding up `bundle install` on CI, for example when a docker container is used to run the tests, you could use `--path`. This will use gems in the given path unless they are not present, otherwise it will download them to that location.

This assumes the CI build can mount a persistent volume inside the docker container. So for example if the CI machine has a directory `/var/cache/drone` which can be mounted in the docker container as `./cache` then you can do:

```
bundle install --without=development --quiet --path=cache
```

Comment: It installs the gems in the `cache` directory instead of using it as a cache: _Bundled gems are installed into `/cache-ci/bundle`_.

Comment: I believe it installs them there first time, i.e. if they do not already exist, then uses those installed on subsequent bundle installs. See: https://bundler.io/bundle_install.html